# How can I prevent code chunks from being run written when exporting to MS Word in Quarto?

Tags: r, quarto

I've written a book in Quarto; however, an MS Word copy of the document will also be attached as well. However, for the MS Word copy, the code will be attached an an appendix rather than in-line. Is there an option for when rendering to MS Word to not have the code display, but for it still to display when rendering as HTML?

Comment: Have you try conditional content https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/conditional.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The follow minimal working example illustrates what you want:

```
---
title: "MWE"
---

::: {.content-visible when-format="html"}

Will only appear in HTML.

:::

::: {.content-visible when-format="docx"}

Will only appear in DOCX.

:::
```